# plsql: Replace 15 line SELECT query called in C#?

Tags: c#, plsql, visual-studio-2013, oracle11g, .net-4.5

My background is `sql server` so please bear with me.

I have a snippet of c# code that runs a 15-line query that returns a resultset. This is what the snippet looks like:

```
public DataSet Oracle_LongComplexQuery()
{

    string oradb = "DATA SOURCE=OUR_SERVER:1521/XE;" +
        "PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=USER; password=PASS; Pooling=False;";

    string sql =
        "SELECT USERNAME, " +
        "USER_ID, " +
        "PASSWORD, " +
        "ACCOUNT_STATUS, " +
        "LOCK_DATE, " +
        "EXPIRY_DATE, " +
        "DEFAULT_TABLESPACE, " +
        "TEMPORARY_TABLESPACE, " +
        "CREATED, " +
        "PROFILE, " +
        "INITIAL_RSRC_CONSUMER_GROUP, " +
        "EXTERNAL_NAME, " +
        "PASSWORD_VERSIONS, " +
        "EDITIONS_ENABLED, " +
        "AUTHENTICATION_TYPE " +
        "from " +
        "dba_users";

    OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradb);
    conn.Open();
    OracleCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = sql;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
    try
    {
        adapter.Fill(ds);
    }
    catch (OracleException ex)
    {
        string er = ex.Message;
    }


    return ds;

}
```

Instead of calling the 15-line query, I would like to create a stored procedure or function that will make this same `Select` without the 15 lines. IN tsql, it would be a stored procedure that I would call as `exec usp_getUsersInfo`.

Since I mostly work with `tsql`, I thought a stored procedure would be the way to go. But it's not. Just to return a resultset the SP needs to have a `SYS_REFCURSOR` parameter to store the data and a separate `PRINT` (at least in SQL Developer) to view the ref cursor.

With a function I wouldn't need the `PRINT` statement, but I Still need the
`SYS_REFCURSOR` that stores the data.

The problem with `SYS_REFCURSOR` is that 1) the whole resultset is stored in the `refcursor`, similar to a dataset, that's then displayed on the screen (instead of showing immediate results). 2) It's happened a few times that I get a `GC Overhead Limit Exceeded Error` with lots of data.

In any case, I don't want to create an object that needs a parameter just to view a resultset. I simply want to replace the 15-line select statement with one line.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is the problem the length of the query? I.e the string size? Or the time to run the query ia long and it returns lots of data? If the string is long and you feel it is reducing the readability of the code (personally I think it is fine.) You could extract it into a resource file? Or perhaps create a view and just select all fields from that view

Comment: I think the issue here is with using `SYS_REFCURSOR`. OP's previous question's accepted answer involved a `PRINT` statement at the end, so this question follows on that to be able to use it from C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My background is in SQL Server, too, and I've had to dabble in Oracle so I feel your pain.  Oracle has different language contexts (I'm sure there's a better way to describe it) and not everything can be done in every context like in SQL Server.

The good news is that although what you have to do to get that to work in SQL Developer, for example, may involve `PRINT` statements, the `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess` package's ADO.NET provider implementation is pretty good about making `SYS_REFCURSOR` fairly easy to work with.

Starting with the stored procedure, it's pretty simple.  Open the `CUR` output cursor and let it read the results of the query you want.  (You may want/need to specify the owner and/or package name with the procedure name.)

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MY_GET_USERS
(
    CUR OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
IS
BEGIN
    OPEN CUR FOR
    SELECT
        USERNAME,
        USER_ID,
        PASSWORD,
        ACCOUNT_STATUS,
        LOCK_DATE,
        EXPIRY_DATE,
        DEFAULT_TABLESPACE,
        TEMPORARY_TABLESPACE,
        CREATED,
        PROFILE,
        INITIAL_RSRC_CONSUMER_GROUP,
        EXTERNAL_NAME,
        PASSWORD_VERSIONS,
        EDITIONS_ENABLED,
        AUTHENTICATION_TYPE
    from
        dba_users;
END;
```

On the C# side, you just need to add a `RefCursor` parameter to the `OracleCommand` object with the right parameter type specified.

```cs
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

using (OracleCommand command = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = "MY_GET_USERS";
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    var curParameter = command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter()
    {
        ParameterName = "CUR",
        Direction = ParameterDirection.Output,
        OracleDbType = OracleDbType.RefCursor  // NOT OracleDbTypeEx
    });

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter();
    adapter.Fill(ds, (OracleRefCursor)curParameter.Value);
}
```

It may seem odd to use `ExecuteNonQuery` to get a result set, but the results are in an output parameter, not the same kind of result set that you'd get by calling `ExecuteReader` with SQL Server.

Note the comment about the `OracleDbType` and `OracleDbTypeEx` properties.  If you set the `OracleDbTypeEx` property, the `Value` property will be set to an `OracleDataReader` object.  By setting the `OracleDbType` property, the `Value` property will be set to an `OracleRefCursor` object, which `adapter.Fill` uses above.  Either can be used if you want to get an `OracleDataReader` object and read the results yourself.

```
// OracleDbType
using (var reader = ((OracleRefCursor)curParameter.Value).GetDataReader())

// OracleDbTypeEx
using (var reader = ((OracleDataReader)curParameter.Value))
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why didn't you use a function? You wouldn't need a `RefCursor` as parameter and you can call it as `select my_oracle_function from dual;`.

Comment: Lack of familiarity is all. You said both, and a stored procedure was on the *"I know I can help you"* side while a function was on the *"I don't have time to learn enough to help you"* side. When I last "dabbled", I was working on a product that had stored procedures (maintained by DB admin-devs) and they were called by both C# and Java code. More power to you if you can do it with functions.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for all your help.